# how to use append after load. jquery

Tags: jquery

All. 
I am using jquery. And I want to append element into loaded html from file (using "load"). It doesn't work.

Is it possible, to use append after load?

Comment: keep trying it will work... good luck, the answer to your question is yes!

Comment: Putting the append inside the load() callback should do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.get` instead. `$.load` is specifically for loading the returned data into an element such as a div.

```
$.get('url', function( data ){
    $('#your-div').append( data ); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is:

```
    $("#myDiv").load("/Controller/View", function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
    if (statusTxt == "success") {
        $("#myDiv").append('<input type="hidden" name="hdnText" value="8" />');
    }
    if (statusTxt == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
});
```